# Convert Text File into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, text

I want to create a dataframe from a textfile. I **scraped** some data from a website and wrote it into a .txt file. There are 10 'columns', as shown in the first 10 lines of the text file. Can anyone help me with seperating the lines into the respective columns in a pandas dataframe format? Much appreciated!

The following is an example of the text file. I would like the first 10 lines to be the column names and the subsequent lines to be under the respective columns.

```
NFT Collection
Volume (ETH)
Market Cap (ETH)
Max price (ETH)
Avg price (ETH)
Min price (ETH)
% Opensea+Rarible
#Transactions
#Wallets
Contract date
Axies | Axie Infinity
4,884
480,695
5.24
.0563
.0024
0
86,807
2,389,981
189d ago
Sandbox's LANDs
578
112,989
6
1.11
.108
100%
394
12,879
700d ago
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another variation:

```
from io import StringIO

with open("input.txt", "r") as file:
    data = [line.strip() for line in file]
data = StringIO("\n".join(";".join(data[i:i+10]) for i in range(0, len(data), 10)))
df = pd.read_csv(data, delimiter=";")
```

The upside: You don't have to convert numbers from string to `int`/`float` etc., the `pd.read_csv` does it. The downside: You have to make sure the delimiter (used in the `join` and `pd.read_csv`) is a character that doesn't occur in the input.

Answer (score 0):

###### Update

Filling your DataFrame directly in the loop should be the most efficient memory-wise. This method also avoids loading the whole text file at once:

```
txt_file = "path/to/your/file"

COL_COUNT = 10

with open(txt_file, "r") as f:
    col = [next(f).strip() for i in range(COL_COUNT)]
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col) 
    i = COL_COUNT
    while line:=f.readline():
        if i % COL_COUNT == 0:
            row = []
        row.append(line.strip())
        if i % COL_COUNT == COL_COUNT - 1:
            df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([row], columns=col))
        i += 1

    df.set_index(col[0], inplace=True) # get rid of row index
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
                      Volume (ETH) Market Cap (ETH) Max price (ETH) Avg price (ETH) Min price (ETH) % Opensea+Rarible #Transactions   #Wallets Contract date
NFT Collection
Axies | Axie Infinity        4,884          480,695            5.24           .0563           .0024                 0        86,807  2,389,981      189d ago
Sandbox's LANDs                578          112,989               6            1.11            .108              100%           394     12,879      700d ago
```

###### Update 2

The list approach is still faster but might claim more memory with big files:

```
txt_file = "path/to/your/file"

COL_COUNT = 10

table = []
with open(txt_file, "r") as f:
    col = [next(f).strip() for i in range(COL_COUNT)]
    i = COL_COUNT
    while line:=f.readline():
        if i % COL_COUNT == 0:
            row = []
        row.append(line.strip())
        if i % COL_COUNT == COL_COUNT - 1:
            table.append(row)
        i += 1

    df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=col)
    df.set_index(col[0], inplace=True) # get rid of row index
    print(df)
```

Comment: This looks good. You could just warn OP that all the fields are just strings. BTW, you could also use the first line as the column names...

Comment: `f.readlines()` returns a `list`, not a generator (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines)). So, I don't think this _"This method also avoids loading the whole text file at once:"_  is correct?

Comment: Thank you for bringing it up! damn I was so sure about this one I didn't even take the time to check... It's now fixed (hopefully ;-))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text file is called `foo.txt`, first we can build a dictionary for your data, using:

```
foo = {}
with open('foo.txt') as f:
    head = [next(f).strip() for x in range(10)]
    for i in range(500):
        foo[i] = [next(f).strip() for x in range(10)]
```

Then simply create the dataframe using the `from_dict` method:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(foo, columns=head, orient='index')
```

Giving you:

```
    NFT Collection  Volume (ETH)    Market Cap (ETH)    Max price (ETH) Avg price (ETH) Min price (ETH) % Opensea+Rarible   #Transactions   #Wallets    Contract date
0   Axies | Axie Infinity   4,884   480,695 5.24    .0563   .0024   0   86,807  2,389,981   189d ago
1   Sandbox's LANDs 578 112,989 6   1.11    .108    100%    394 12,879  144d ago
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```py
text = """NFT Collection
Volume (ETH)
Market Cap (ETH)
Max price (ETH)
Avg price (ETH)
Min price (ETH)
% Opensea+Rarible
#Transactions
#Wallets
Contract date
Axies | Axie Infinity
4,884
480,695
5.24
.0563
.0024
0
86,807
2,389,981
189d ago
Sandbox's LANDs
578
112,989
6
1.11
.108
100%
394
12,879
700d ago"""

text = text.split('\n')
text = [text[i:(i+10)] for i in range(0,len(text),10)]
df = pd.DataFrame(text[1:],columns=text[0])
```